# How to match data with two df in double loop in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I am having trouble matching data by the following key:

The first data frame contains the columns *ID* and *Distance*. As below.

| ID | Distance |
| --- | --- |
| A | 30 |
| B | 50 |
| C | 300 |
| D | 120 |
| E | 50 |

The second data frame contains numbers that change in years (*Year*) and are different from the data included in *Distance* column of the first data frame. As below.

| Year | 30 | 50 | 120 | 300 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 0.12 | 0.20 | 0.31 | 0.45 |
| 2021 | 0.14 | 0.23 | 0.33 | 0.46 |
| 2022 | 0.16 | 0.26 | 0.35 | 0.47 |
| 2023 | 0.18 | 0.29 | 0.37 | 0.48 |
| 2024 | 0.20 | 0.32 | 0.39 | 0.49 |

My question is. How do effectively assign these data in the third empty data frame, which contains different *IDs* characterized by different *Distance* and years for which the rate from *Distance* is varying. The third final df with examples of expected data is above. I am tryfing to use double loop but i am faild. Basically I am newbie in R and programming.

| Year | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 |  | ex. 0.20 |  |  |  |
| 2021 |  |  | ex. 0.33 |  |  |
| 2022 |  |  |  |  | ex. 0,26 |
| 2023 | ex. 0.18 |  |  |  |  |
| 2024 |  |  |  | ex. 0.39 |  |

Many thanks for any suggestions and solutions.

Comment: It looks to me like the result is identical to the second data frame except for two changes: (a) the column names are changed from the distances to the corresponding ID in the first data frame, and (b) in the case of two IDs having the same distance (like B and E) that column is duplicated in the result so that both IDs show up. Does that sound right? I want to make sure I understand before doing a solution.

Comment: It would also help if you would `dput()` the sample data so it is copy/pasteable. Column names that are numbers are unusual and hard to get - are the column names in the second data frame actually `"30", "50"` etc. or are they really `"X30", "X50"` or `"V30", "V50"` or something like that? If you could share `dput(DF2[1:5, 1:5])` to share the first 5 rows and 5 columns of `DF2` (or whatever your second data frame's name is) that would help us a lot.

Comment: @GregorThomas To answer your 1 question - you understand so well. As requested, I performed `dput()` -> `structure(list(Year = c(2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021), 20 = c(0.26, 0.28, 0.30, 0.32, 0.34), 30 = c(0.4, 0.42, 0.44, 0.46, 0.48), 50 = c(0.54, 0.56, 0.58, 0.6, 0.62), 70 = c(0.67, 0.68, 0.69, 0.70, 0.71 )), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")`   There are dummy numbers included

Comment: Analyzing this data, I thought it might be helpful to create 10 different df's to account for, let's say, 20, 30, 50 by year.

Comment: Ugh, no. Creating many different data frames is rarely a good idea. Put it in a long format and use `dplyr` or `data.table` to do operations by group instead.

Comment: Thanks! Next time please put the `dput()` in your question, the comment formatting eats special characters like backticks making it less helpful than it would be in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of the `DF1$Distance` values are present in the `DF2` column names (and vice versa), then this should work:

```
# select DF2 columns by the DF1 distance values
result = DF2[c("Year", as.character(DF1$Distance))] 
# change the names to the ID values
names(result)[-1] = DF1$ID)
```

In the small `dput()` sample, however, there are some `Distance` values that are not columns in `DF2`. Just in case this could happen in your real data, here is a slightly more complicated solution where the matching columns are created in the result and the missing columns are added as `NA` values:

```
DF1$in_df2 = DF1$Distance %in% names(DF2)

result = DF2[c("Year", as.character(DF1$Distance[DF1$in_df2]))]
names(result)[-1] =  DF1$ID[DF1$in_df2]
result[DF1$ID[!DF1$in_df2]] = NA
result
#   Year    A    B    E  C  D
# 1 2017 0.40 0.54 0.54 NA NA
# 2 2018 0.42 0.56 0.56 NA NA
# 3 2019 0.44 0.58 0.58 NA NA
# 4 2020 0.46 0.60 0.60 NA NA
# 5 2021 0.48 0.62 0.62 NA NA
```

---

Using this sample data:

```
DF1 = read.table(text = 'ID     Distance
A   30
B   50
C   300
D   120
E   50', header = T)

DF2 = structure(list(Year = c(2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021), `20` = c(0.26,
 0.28, 0.30, 0.32, 0.34), `30` = c(0.4, 0.42, 0.44, 0.46, 0.48), `50` = 
c(0.54, 0.56, 0.58, 0.6, 0.62), `70` = c(0.67, 0.68, 0.69, 0.70, 0.71 )), 
row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```